# task scheduler powershell scripts never ends

Tags: powershell, task, scheduler

I have a script that works great manually. However, when I schedule it in Task Scheduler, the script never ends and so the next time it tries to run, it fails because the prior instance is still running. The script itself takes a few seconds to complete the first time or when run manually. Here is the script:

```
$source = "\\server1\upload"
$destination = "\\server2\upload"
$logfile = "c:\Scripts\fileMover\log.txt"
$table = Get-ChildItem $source -include *
foreach ($file in $table){
    $filename = $file.FullName
    #write-host $filename
    try
    {
        move-item -LiteralPath $filename -destination $destination -force
        $body = "Successfully moved $filename to $destination"
        $subject = "fileMover Succeeded"
    }
    catch
    {
        $body = "Failed to move $filename to $destination"
        $subject = "fileMover Failed"
    }
    finally
    {
        $body | out-file $logfile -append -width 1000 -encoding ascii
        Send-MailMessage -To "filemoverconfirmations@domain.com" -From "uploader@domain.com" -Subject $subject -SmtpServer "10.1.10.1" -Body $body
        exit
    }
}
exit
```

The script is scheduled with the following settings:

- Run whether user is logged or not (user account has been granted log in as a batch program privilege)
- Run with highest privileges
- Triggers Daily, every 2 minute
- Action: Start a Program powershell -file c:\Scripts\upload.ps1

As a workaround, I configured the task to automatically stop after 1 minute. However, I'm concerned that in certain circumstances -- such as a large number of large files -- the script may get terminated before completing fully.

The script needs to run every 2 minutes.

Comment: Try appending `'Start-Transcript "C:\Scripts\Upload-Transcript.txt"` to the start of your script, and see if it's throwing errors when running via task scheduler, it may be prompting for email credentials or something, and getting stuck there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Connor. I did as suggested, but no errors were thrown.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to the send-mailmessage. When run manually, the script runs within a few seconds. However, when run as a task, it takes around a minute per file. Rather than sending a confirmation for each file processed, I rewrote the script to send the a single email at the end of the process. This doesn't explain the delay when run as a task, but it has fixed my problem for now.

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem when trying to execute `.ps1` file directly.  Execute `Powershell` and feed it your script as a parameter.

Scheduled Task Actions Tab:

```
Program\script: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Add Arguments (optional):
     `-command & 'E:\PowerShell_scripts\Script_name.ps1’`

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. There seems to be some formatting issues with your powershell script there. You may want to use the following guide on how to format code https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Is it just me or  is it  ... command 'E:\PowerShell_scripts\Script_name.ps1’ (note no &)

Answer (score 6):

This is going to sound silly, but I initially had the same problem as detailed in the other answers - trying to run the `.ps1` script directly instead of via `powershell.exe`. I worked that part out since I saw Notepad opening, but after correcting my mistake it was still reporting *Running*.

The solution? [image] Refresh

Comment: I can't even... This was the solution.

Comment: @THEJOATMON Sometimes the simplest solutions are the easiest ones to overlook 

Comment: Something else silly to keep in mind. If you happen to separately have a PowerShell session open for debugging your script, close it out before testing the task via Task Scheduler. I was scratching my head wondering why it was still running well beyond when I expected it to finish. 

Answer (score 3):

For the "Start a program" action, list `powershell` as the "Program/script" and put the path to the script you want to run in the "Add arguments (optional)" box.

The action never finishes if you try to "run" a PowerShell script by listing it as the "Program/script" directly, because Notepad is the default application associated with the `.ps1` extension (to help users avoid accidentally running a PowerShell script), and so it opens the script in Notepad in the background instead of executing it. Notepad then never closes itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, press `F5` to refresh, and check if the `Running` status has changed.
2. If **program/script** filled with the script path, should make sure *powershell.exe* is the default program to run the runscript.
3. If not sure, fill the **program/script** with `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`,
   and fill the **Add arguments (optional)** with
   `-File "C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\automation.ps1"`

Answer (score 0):

Action

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Argument

```
-File "E:\Scripts\script.ps1"
```